# Cant start event sqlos.wait_info

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

After I create this event and I want start it, it throws a error.
I create event with following code:

```
create event session WaitTest on server
add event sqlos.wait_info
(WHERE sqlserver.session_id=61 and duration>0)
add target package0.asynchronous_file_target
(set filename=N'c:\wait_stats.xel')
go
```

and start it with this:

```
alter event session WaitTest on server state = start;
```

and it throws this error:

The target, "CE79811F-1A80-40E1-8F5D-7445A3F375E7.package0.asynchronous_file_target", encountered a configuration error during initialization.  Object cannot be added to the event session.

Does anyone know where is the problem and how this problem fix?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's SQL Server's cryptic way of telling you that it cannot create the xel file in the root of C: drive. I believe there is another piece of information in the error message, about the operating system error it encountered.

Create a folder for it and give read/write permissions to SQL Server account.

Answer (score 0):

I was pulling my hair out over this.

I was using SSMS to run an *Extended Events* script similar to this against a SQL Server on a different machine and forgot that the "C:" drive being referred to would be the "C:" drive on the server, not the local machine. Duh!

Once I granted the correct permissions (I just gave a dedicated folder *Full Control* permissions for the *Everyone* account) the error disappeared.